# Change Visual Studio.Net 2008 IDE Background Image

Tags: visual-studio

I remember seeing a way to change the background of the VS.Net 2008 IDE code editor to an image, how can I do this?

thanks

Answer (score 4):

You can add an image to the code editor with [SlickEdit Gadgets](http://www.slickedit.com/content/view/441) (free); see my [post here](http://marcgravell.blogspot.com/2009/04/handy-editor-tweaks-with-slickedit.html) for an example - or just:

[image: Gadgets image]

Comment: @AmrElGarhy for 2005 / 2008 I think you can use [the gallery](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/0253125F-285F-4490-AB2A-0F96011F20A6) - I suspect they didn't see the investment in updating them to 2010 / 2012.

Answer (score 3):

Check these:

[Wallpaper for Visual Studio .NET](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/macros/VSWallpaper.aspx)

[#31 Changing the Visual Studio Background Color](http://scottcate.com/tricks/031/)